# Unit testing GAE Blobstore (with nose)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We're using nose with nose-gae for unit testing our controllers and models. We now have code that hits the blob store and files API. We are having a hard time testing those due to lack of testing proxies/mocks. Is there a good way to unit tests these services or lacking unit testing is there a way to automated acceptance test those APIs? TIA.

Comment: Did you take a look at the docs? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting

Comment: Sure did. Followed instructions but wasn't of much help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this for the blobstorage tests:

```
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
from google.appengine.api.blobstore import file_blob_storage

testbed.Testbed()
testbed._blob_storage = file_blob_storage.FileBlobStorage('/tmp/', 'testing')
testbed.init_blobstore_stub()
testbed.init_files_stub()
```

Works well in my tests (though I don't use nose, I use webtest).

Comment: You, sir, are a saint! A gentleman and a scholar. A true benefactor.

Comment: I use this trick too and it is great.  Unfortunately, FileBlobStorage is deprecated so we will all need a new solution sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question so I dug into the nosegae code, and then into the actual testbed code.

All you need to do is set `nosegae_blobstore = True` where you're setting up all the other stubs. This sets up a dict-backed blobstore stub.